# Polymer custom element attribute/property binding with .NET MVC Razor: @DateTime.Now.Year

Tags: html, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer / WebComponentsJS / .NET MVC

I have had good experience with them so far,  I sat down this morning to write tutorial and I started with a very basic example.  However the first binding I do has me at a brick wall.  Can someone explain what is happening with this code and why it would not bind data.  It is a very basic custom element with one property "currentyear". The markup was taken directly from the ASP.NET MVC template in visual studio and placed in this custom element html file.

```
<dom-module id="my-footer">

<template>
    <style>
        /* CSS rules for your element */
    </style>

    <!-- local DOM for your element -->
    <!-- data bindings in local DOM -->
<footer>
    <p>&copy; {{currentyear}} - My Footer Version 1</p>
</footer>
</template>

<script>
    // element registration
    Polymer({
        is: "my-footer",

        // add properties and methods on the element's prototype
        properties: {
            // declare properties for the element's public API
            currentyear: String
        },
        //builtin functions of custom element lifecycle
        created: function () {
            console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' was created');

        },

        attached: function () {
            console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' was attached');
            this.async(function () {
                // access sibling or parent elements here
                // THIS WORKS and displays value in console
                console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' current year is: ' + this.currentyear);
            });
        },

        detached: function () {
            console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' was detached');
        },

        attributeChanged: function (name, type) {
            console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' attribute ' + name + ' was changed to ');
        },

        ready: function (){
            console.log('on READY the value of current year property is: ' + this.currentyear);
        }

    });
</script>
```

```
<my-footer currentyear="@DateTime.Now.Year"></my-footer>
```

[image: console log chrome dev tools]

---

While writing this post I solved my issue but still don't understand why it was not binding with the original markup.

I changed the html markup from this:

```
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; {{currentyear}} - My Footer Version 1</p>
</footer>
```

to this:

```
<footer>
 <p><span>&copy;</span> <span>{{currentyear}}</span><span> - My Footer Version 1</span></p>
</footer>
```

and it worked! at least an hour of my time was spent checking my code over and over before turning to StackOverflow for some input.

I tried this and it also works:

```
<p>&copy; <span>{{currentyear}}</span>  - My Footer Version 1</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle note in the Polymer docs that states:

> [The binding annotation must currently span the entire content of the tag](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html)

That's why adding a wrapping element like you did resolved the issue. From what i found, Polymer does not even allow a white space between the tag and the binding expression.

Comment: Thanks for the input. best regards